# If statement followed by a loop

Tags: syntax, scope, pseudocode

An if statement has a certain condition and then i am using a while loop within the if statement with another condition, will the condition in the if statement be tested in every iteration?

```
LIST-SEARCH'(L,k)
x=L.nil.next
if x!=L.nil
   while x.key!=k
         x=x.next
return x
```

Comment: Can you post your code instead of describing it? I, for one, would find it easier to assist.

Comment: Yes i know , i just gave you a psuedo code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If what you describe is like:

```
if(conditionA)
{
     while(conditionB)
     {
          /* ... */
     }
}
```

Then, no. `conditionA` is tested only once, while `conditionB` is tested to check if the loop should be executed again for each loop run.

Answer (score 1):

The way to know these things without having to ask is to run your program through a debugger and step through the execution of each line. You should notice that the if-test line is only ever hit once, while the test in the while() loop is hit on every iteration. Most IDEs include debuggers with this capability or you can use a command-line utility like gdb.